# Bounding the difference of empirical means of the same unknown distribution?

Tags: probability

Let $ X = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i = 1,\dots, N} \omega_i $ and $Y = \frac{1}{M} \sum_{i = 1, \dots, M} \omega_i$, where the $\omega$'s are bounded and drawn i.i.d. from the same unknown distribution and the two empirical means use different sets of $\omega$'s. Also, let $M \neq N$. Is there a way to lower bound
$$ \Pr(X - Y \leq \gamma), $$
where the probability of is taken over the distribution of $\omega$ and $\gamma$ is a constant? Is there a way to do this without making assumptions on the distribution of $\omega$? Thanks!

Comment: We can conclude *something* if we at least know some moments of $X - Y$.  If we know nothing at all about X or Y, then this is almost certainly ill-posed.

Comment: Thanks. Wouldn't the first moment of $X - Y$ be zero by definition? Would one be able to conclude anything from that?

Comment: Ah, that's a good point.  Yes, we can conclude some things from that; for example, we can conclude that $P(X - Y \leq 0) > 0$...

Comment: Chebyshev's inequality can be helpfull, but you need at least to know the variance ( thus the $2$° centered moment), and it must be finite. Otherwise I'm afraid there can be counterexamples, I doubt such a probability has a specific upperboud (except $1$, that is)

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking if $M = N$, one could use Hoeffding's inequality by defining an r.v. $\xi = \omega_i - \omega_j$ so $X - Y$ becomes the empirical mean of $\xi$ and $E[X - Y] = 0$ but I suppose this could not be done when $M \neq N$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can adapt Hoeffding inequality. Let $a,b$ such that $\omega_i\in[a,b]$ almost surely. Then, you can use Chernoff inequality and the independence between $\omega$'s ("different sets ")
$$\mathbf{P}(X-Y>\gamma)\leq\mathbf{E}\left[e^{s(X-Y)}\right]e^{-s\gamma}=\mathbf{E}\left[e^{sX}\right]\mathbf{E}\left[e^{-sY}\right]e^{-s\gamma}=\left(\prod_{i=1}^N\mathbf{E}\left[e^{\frac{s}{N}\omega_i}\right]\right)\left(\prod_{i=1}^M\mathbf{E}\left[e^{-\frac{s}{M}\omega_i}\right]\right)e^{-s\gamma}$$
for all $s>0$. Now we can use the [Hoeffding's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_lemma) with $\mu=\mathbf{E}[\omega_i]$

$$\mathbf{P}(X-Y>\gamma)\leq e^{N\left(\frac{\mu s}{N}+\frac{s^2(b-a)^2}{8N^2}\right)}e^{M\left(-\frac{\mu s}{M}+\frac{s^2(b-a)^2}{8M^2}\right)}e^{-s\gamma}=e^{s^2\frac{(b-a)^2}{8}(\frac{1}{N}+\frac{1}{M})-s\gamma}$$

So the best bound is to choose $s=\frac{4\gamma}{(b-a)^2}\frac{NM}{N+M}$ and then
$$\mathbf{P}(X-Y\leq\gamma)\geq 1-e^{-\frac{2\gamma^2}{(b-a)^2}\frac{NM}{N+M}}$$